# Why won't my dwarves pick up a pick and go mine?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I've created two copper picks to help my dwarves mine, but they refuse to pick them up.  What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I do have them set to be miners and I do have a dig area set.

Comment: because they're lazy and you don't pay them enough :p

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need two things in addition to the picks.

- Dwarves with the mining labor enabled, as explained [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4992/how-to-train-retrain-dwarves/4995#4995).
- The dwarves might be busy with other things, try turning off other labors.
- An area designated for digging.
- You can designate an area for digging by pressing <kbd>d</kbd>, <kbd>d</kbd> and selecting an area to be mined.  This is easiest if you have an exposed hillside on the map.  If not you may need to go down a [z level](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2010:Z-axis) and designate ramps up (<kbd>d</kbd>, <kbd>r</kbd>) next to your mining area.
- The dwarves must be able to path to this digging area.  If it is separated by z-levels, you must add stairs or ramps.

Comment: If someone wants to break up the text so it's more readable, be my guest.

Comment: HALP there's raccoon blood everywhere...

Comment: @Mechko I thought that was a good sign?

Comment: Ross yes, but its dirty, now

Comment: I had a downwards stair built upwards or something.  I built an up/down stair and now it works.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using Dwarf Therapist by any chance? That had a bug where enabling Mining via DT didn't get the dwarves to actually *do* anything, and you had to disable and re-enable Mining via the game's interface (as in C. Ross's answer).

Another thing to check is whether the picks are not, for some strange reason, forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

Are they able to get to the dig area? I sometimes marked a whole area to be mined, but missed a square connecting it up to the existing walls, so they didn't have a first tile to start digging at.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off the mining labor, unpausing, then turning mining back on for the miner in question (while having a pick that is NOT designated to be dumped, melted, forbidden, or "TSK" (being moved by another dwarf to another stock pile) and having an easily accessible area to dig out)